# Java: Correct use of conditional statements

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am a beginner and I am trying to develop Connect4 game by applying minimax algorithm, I am stuck at the condition that determines whether it's min player turn or max player turn. I've got the feeling it's something reduculs but I've been thinking for two days trying to figure it out.
Any help?

```
private int evaluatePlayerMove(int depth, int maxDepth, int col, int alpha, int beta) {
    boardsAnalyzed++;

    int evaluatedMove=0; // For evaluating min player move or max player move

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, minScore = 0; // For min player

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxScore = 0; // For max player


    if (col != -1) {

    // Check whether it's min player turn or max player turn

    // If it's min player turn then evaluate min move:

    if(//it's min player turn){
        minScore = board.getHeuristicScore(Board.MARK_BLACK, col, depth, maxDepth);
        if(board.blackWinFound()) {
            blackWinFound = true;
            return minScore;
        }


    if (depth == maxDepth) {
        return minScore;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < Board.COLUMNS; c++) {
        if (board.isColumnAvailable(c)) {
            board.mark(c, Board.MARK_RED);
            int value = evaluatePlayerMove(depth + 1, maxDepth, c, alpha, beta);
            board.unset(c);
            if (value < min) {
                min = value;
                if (depth == 0) {
                    column = c;
                }
            }
            if (value < beta) {
                beta = value;
            }
            if (alpha >= beta) {
                return beta;
            }
        }


    }

    if (min == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }
     evaluatedMove = min;
    }


   // If it's max player turn then evaluate max move:

    if(//it's max player turn) {
        maxScore = board.getHeuristicScore(Board.MARK_RED, col, depth, maxDepth);
      if (board.redWinFound()) {
            redWinFound = true;
           return maxScore;
       }
    if (depth == maxDepth) {
        return maxScore;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < Board.COLUMNS; c++) {
        if (board.isColumnAvailable(c)) {
            board.mark(c, Board.MARK_BLACK);
            int value = evaluatePlayerMove(depth + 1, maxDepth, c, alpha, beta);
            board.unset(c);
            if (value > max) {
                max = value;
                if (depth == 0) {
                    column = c;
                }
            }
            if (value > alpha) {
                alpha = value;
            }
            if (alpha >= beta) {
                return alpha;
            }
        }


    }
    if (max == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }

     evaluatedMove= max;
    } 


} 
return evaluatedMove;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most real-time AI situations, it is your AI program versus a human player. So, usually, if you are building a min-max tree, the AI program will only be either min or max, and the same will be the root of the tree. For e.g. if you try at the AI program as max, the root of the tree will always remain max and you need only compute moves for max (min moves will be user inputs). For such situation, i would recommend using the depth of the tree as your checking condition.

```
if(root == max){
     for any node n:
            if(n.depth%2 == 0){
                  n is max
            }
            else{
                 n is min
            }
 }
```

Because depth is usually used in almost all problems, it would be an efficient way.

However, if it is an homework problem and you indeed need to compute moves for both min and max, I would recommend using a instance static boolean variable isMax which should be flipped after every move.